# How to deal with duplicate target names in reStructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

Example:

```
foo is a tool used to do foo.

Download_

.. _Download: http://example.com/foo

blah blah blah (omit a lot of paragraphs)

bar is another tool to do bar.

Download_

.. _Download: http://example.com/bar
```

Since `Download` points to different urls, docutilus gives this error report:

```
Duplicate target name, cannot be used as a
unique reference: "Download".
```

While in markdown, I can specify different id for this two `Download`:

```
[Download][download-foo]
[download-foo]: http://example.com/foo
[Download][download-bar]
[download-bar]: http://example.com/bar
```

How can I do similar things in reStructuredText?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option one

As @mzjn pointed out, make target name more clear:

```
`Download foo`_

.. _Download foo: http://example.com/foo

`Download bar`_

.. _Download bar: http://example.com/bar
```

### Option two

From [docutils-user maillist](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.text.docutils.user/4181/):

Use Anonymous hyperlink:

```
Download__


__ http://example.com/foo


Download__

__ http://example.com/bar
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from [the documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#reference-names), reference names in ReST documents share a common namespace, so they must be unique. I can't think of anything better than this:

```
foo is a tool used to do foo.

`Download foo`_

.. _Download foo: http://example.com/foo

blah blah blah (omit a lot of paragraphs)

bar is another tool to do bar.

`Download bar`_

.. _Download bar: http://example.com/bar
```

Comment: Then what about this?  `Our product integrates with \`sphinx\`_ (omit a lot of paragraphs) Powered by \`sphinx\`_ `, where the first `sphinx` links to the homepage of sphinx search, and the second `sphinx` links to the homepage of sphinx documentation builder.