# How to have same text in two links with restructured text?

Tags: python, restructuredtext

Here is what I would like to do:

```
1. `link <http://www.google.com>`__
2. `link <http://www.yahoo.com>`__
```

To obtain:

```
<ol>
<li><a href="http://www.google.com">link</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.yahoo.com">link</a></li>
</ol>
```

The context is a list of publications, where I want them all to have a link marked "DOI" at the end.

However, this seems to fails with:

```
<string>:3: (WARNING/2) Duplicate explicit target name: "doi".
```

The exact error seems to depend on the version of docutils that I use, but they've all failed.

Is there a way to generate multiple links with the same text in restructured text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with duplicate target names in reStructuredText?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843052/how-to-deal-with-duplicate-target-names-in-restructuredtext)

Comment: The question is obsolete. Unless using an antique version of Docutils the error cannot be reproduced and, the expected behaviour is what Docutils does.

Answer (score 164, accepted):

The warning

> (WARNING/2) Duplicate explicit target name:foo

occurs when you use the same text for two different links in "Named hyperlink references":

```
`Foo <http://example.org>`_
`Foo <http://example.com>`_
```

To circumvent it, use *anonymous* [hyperlink references](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#hyperlink-references) with double underscores:

```
`Foo <http://example.org>`__
`Foo <http://example.com>`__
```

This works without a warning on docutils 0.8.1.

Comment: I think this is true only on more recent versions. I can confirm that I now got this result (which is, arguably, the better result). I am accepting this new answer.

Answer (score 16):

I think you'll want to use anonymous hyperlinks:

```
1. `link`__
2. `link`__

__ http://www.google.com
__ http://www.yahoo.com
```

Keep in mind that the order they're referred to in the document is important.  More information can be found [here](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#anonymous-hyperlinks).

Answer (score 4):

Seems like you need a newline and two underscores.

This is what I do:

```
What is that Process object good for? `(html)
<process.html>`__
`(html) 
<other.process.rst>`__
```

to obtain:

```
What is that Process object good for? 
<a class="reference external" href="process.html">(html)</a>
<a class="reference external" href="process.rst">(html)</a>
```